# Creating subset in R

Tags: r

I have an assignment question with a data in which there are variables 'newc', 'age', 'male' and so on..however there is a variable 'male' which is, male=1 if the individual is male and male=0 if otherwise. But right now I am asked the question below,

Suppose someone on the data analytics team tells you to run a regression of newc on age using male individuals only. What do you find in this regression?
(Hint: to generate a new dataset consisting of a subset of observations, use the command “mydata_DC=subset(mydata,male==1)”, where mydata is your original dataset).

For this assignment, I named my data just simply 'data'. To create the subset with only males, I used the code "data_DC=subset(data$male==1)" as I followed the hint from the question. However, in R it just says error. Now I am rather confused. Could you help tell me why there is an error?

Comment: The `subset()` function needs two parameters: the data, and then the logical expression. There should be a comma between them.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the function, because gave wrong input. If you type in the console: `?subset` and go to examples, you'll see the following:

```
subset(airquality, Temp > 80, select = c(Ozone, Temp))
subset(airquality, Day == 1, select = -Temp)
subset(airquality, select = Ozone:Wind)
```

If I tell you the dataframe is 'airquality', does that make it clear enough?